# How to see function body in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

Is there a way in GNU Octave to print source code of a user-defined function?

For example, I've defined a function in the interactive prompt:

```
octave:nn> function y = f(x); y = x; endfunction;
```

Now is there a way to look up this function definition later in the prompt? Something like

```
octave:nn> showsource("f")
ans = function y = f(x); y = x; endfunction;
```

Comment: I have submitted a related feature request in the Octave bug-tracker linked to this question https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?50347

Answer (score 7):

For displaying the content of any function, use the [type](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/XREFtype.html) function:

```
    >> function y = f(x); y = x; endfunction;
    >> type ("f")
    f is the command-line function:

    function y = f (x)
      y = x;
    endfunction
```

Comment: Nice! Is this new in 4.2.0? I remember trying it when this post originally occurred and it didn't work! Now it seems you can you can even spawn it on the current path by doing `edit f.m` !

Comment: Yes, the [change was added May 2015](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/abf85f8cbd6c) what resulted in version 4.2.0 to close [bug #40462](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?40462), having almost the same issue as you had.

Answer (score 3):

If the function is defined with `inline`, you can use `formula` or `char` to see the body of the function:

```
>> f = inline("x");
>> formula(f)
ans = x
>> char(f)
ans = x
```

Comment: I can't mark this as an answer because it provides a way to see a source of inlined function, but not the source of `regular` function. I guess inlining complex functions also would be impractical.